# Multi days event in allDay slot don't pan out to the other days

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I'm working on Fullcalendar v2.8.0 and I'm trying to make events that span over multiple days to go in the Allday slot instead of taking a lot of the view. The main purpose is for paid vacations to appeare, my clients would enjoy this feature and I've been asked to work on that.

[I would like it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwcX0.png) but for now it just looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVpXG.png) the event is supposed to end on the 31st and yet it doesn't span all the way there.
I've looked at a lot of other posts and I feel a bit lost because the app is very big, it works with silex/symfony, laravel and ajax requests so there's a lot of files to look through.

I'd be happy if anyone could just point me to where I should look and help me by explaining to me how FullCalendar really works.

From what I gathered this is where I should be looking at :

```
eventRender: function(event, element,view) {
    box = $('.checkbox-actor[type="checkbox"][value="' + event.actor_id + '"]');
    box2 = $('.checkbox-office[type="checkbox"][value="' + event.office_id + '"]');

    if (box.is( ":checked") && box2.is( ":checked" ) ) {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My main problem is that, when I put the event as an AllDay event it doesn't go to the other days like in the exemple provided, however if I don't tag it as an AllDay event it just takes way too much space.

I'd be happy to provide any additional code but I'd be happiest if you could give me some key words that I can enter in the search bar as there are multiple files that all go above 500 to 1000 lines of code.

Comment: No, that eventRender code is irrelevant to your problem - all it's doing is deciding whether or not to even display the event at all, based on the value of some checkboxes. It doesn't determine where it is placed on the calendar, or the way it is displayed.

Comment: What you'd really need to show us is the JSON data for the event, including its start and end dates. If I had to guess, I would say your issue is likely to be happening because of the way fullCalendar treats end dates as being **exclusive** (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object) - this is something people ask about frequently and have often either misunderstood or failed to notice it in the documentation.